# inject js into iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Im trying to inject js into iframe in some website ( not localhost) from console and get :

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin X from accessing a
>   cross-origin frame.

but then is see code examples like 
[Smaple](https://codepen.io/bentheartist/pen/PPmZRa)

```
var $doc = $(document.getElementById('test').contentWindow.document),
    $booTitle = $('<h1>boo!</h1>'),
    $poopParagraph = $('<p>poop!</p>');

$doc.find('head').append($("<script />", {
    src: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'
}));

$doc.find('head').append($("<script />", {
    html: '$doc.find("body").append($booTitle);'
}));

$doc.find('body').append($poopParagraph);

$doc.find('head').append($('<ref'))
```

and chrome extensions who are able to do it...

So what is the difference?

I guess the codepen is the same Origin.
But what about the chrome extension it runs locally like the console.

is it because of permissions?

Comment: It relates to CORS and permissions. A search on CORS here will probably help you find what you need.

Comment: What do you mean permissions?
Does a chrome extension have more permissions than me running in the console?